# Store button response

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons on my screen (1 and 2). I want to be able to store which button is clicked on in a variable and add 5 (if button 1) or subtract 5 (if button 2)to a total score. How do I store which button has been clicked on?

Comment: Can you show us a code sample?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Do you have a variable to store your value?  Do you have handlers for the buttons' click events?  What isn't working?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service - you're expected to have had a go and understand the fundamentals (or ask about the fundamentals).  Have a read of [tour] and [ask].

Comment: No need to store it in a variable.  Add a class to the selected button.  The DOM holds state already

Comment: The question is also ambiguous as to the functionality desired.  Do you want repeated clicks to repetitively repeat the adjustment, or should it only function as a toggle between +/- 5 from a base value?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var total = 0

$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
  total = total + 5;
  $("#txt1").val(total);
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function() {
  total = total - 5;
  $("#txt1").val(total);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">+5</button>
<button id="btn2">-5</button>

<input type="text" value="0" id="txt1" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pzfh1m05/